# Is there a conventional way of searching for lands in a mono-red deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-manabase

I'm constructing a mono-red deck and I was wondering whether there are any options for land search / ramp for this kind of deck? I don't want to combine my deck with green for land searching.

I was thinking about cards like this:

[image: druidic satchel]

Any ideas?

**Edit:
As a second thought: I'm looking for more mana in fact not land.
I'm constructing a Standard (Type II) deck.**

Comment: I recommend saying "Standard (Type II)" since newer players might not know what the old Types mean.

Comment: Ok! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mike Flores said Druidic Satchel is a worthwhile faux-planeswalker for Standard (the trick is to double up on whatever you need most by sometimes using it on your upkeep).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Solemn Simulacrum](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236907) is good colorless fetch (and draw).

[Traveler's Amulet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=237357) and [Horizon Spellbomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=210229) can get lands into your hand.

[Caged Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214345) will get you lots of mana (but no lands) as will [Koth of the Hammer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212238).

[Iron Myr](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194168) is a good mana producing creature

[Infernal Plunge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=235603) and [Geosurge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218004) can also have their uses.

[Fiery Fall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243493) is the only mono-red card that could be considered land fetch but it's not Standard.

Other non-Standard methods for increased mana in red can be:

[Extraplanar Lens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=49440)

[Gauntlet of Power](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=124220)

[Gauntlet of Might](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202629)

[Mana Flare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=159264)

Comment: I just searched all cards on google. After that you created the links for them. :) :) Thanks for the info by the way. What do you think about mana-giving creatures? (like Llanovar Elves)

Comment: I chose to list non-Standard cards as well since they are useful for people with similar questions outside of Standard and because Standard is an ever changing format.

Comment: @edem - good point.  I added a few more cards.

Comment: Good point too.

Comment: I thnk that I'll choose Iron Myr since I'm using Goblin Gaveleer and Kuldotha Phoenix. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Short version: in the current Standard environment, play Sphere of the Suns if you want to play 4-drops early, play Koth of the Hammer if you want to play 6-drops early or get a lot of mana for a big X spell; make sure you don't short yourself on lands; if you want to experiment with a rogue deck, try Geosurge.

Long version:

In the modern color pie, red is the color for fast-mana effects (called "rituals" after the old [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=54)). Unfortunately, the two ritual effects available in Standard, [Geosurge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218004) and [Infernal Plunge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=235603), don't quite hit the same sweet spot as [Seething Song](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243487) used to. Geosurge is still good enough to drop a big finisher (Inferno Titan, Wurmcoil Engine, maybe Balefire Dragon if you want to get cute) on turn 4, but that requires having both the enabler and the big creature in your starting 10 -- and remember that contemporary mono-red doesn't really have filtering or card draw. Most people probably figure it's safer to just play a strong four-drop.

I know some folks have experimented with B/R [Heartless Summoning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244678) to play Inferno Titans quickly (turn 3 Titan using [Priest of Urabrask](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218037), or turn 3 Urabrask into turn 4 hasty Titan). Those decks are rather inconsistent and vulnerable to disruption, though.

Honestly if you need **consistent** early-turn mana acceleration in a color other than green, I'd just play [Sphere of the Suns](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213776). Like Myr, it's still an easy target for Ancient Grudge, but at least with Sphere half your mana base won't be blown up by a Day of Judgment.

[Solemn Simulacrum](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236907) is a great card for getting you from 4 mana to 6. As a bonus, you get to draw a card when it dies. That's nearly always a 2-for-1, and often a 3-for-1 if you can trade creatures.

The best big-mana card in red is [Koth of the Hammer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212238). His -2 ability gives you a lot of mana easily (if you have Koth and 5 lands on turn 5, for instance, you can play Inferno Titan and have mana open to stop Mana Leak, or hit your opponent with a 9-point Devil's Play). Koth's -5 ability is excellent at breaking through board stalls.

Also, with all these tricks, it's important to remember that ramp doesn't replace land drops. Most red decks running Koth as their big threat will want to consistently hit their 4th land drop on turn 4, and that means running 24 lands rather than the 20-22 you can sometimes get away with in aggro decks.

Comment: What I have right now is a goblin deck, but it is just a prototype: http://deckstats.net/deck-867122-6f9250174eeba9d2f862ae47749e20e5-en.html

Comment: I think that sphere is better for me, but it is yet to be decided which cards will I remove to put it in...

Comment: My rule of thumb: if you plan to hardcast anything costing more than 4 cmc, you need at least 24 lands. Note how Solar Flare often runs *26 lands*, for instance. The reasoning is simple: mana acceleration costs resources, land drops are free. Paying 2 for Sphere of the Suns or Rampant Growth on turn 2 only to miss your turn 3 land drop is basically trading a turn to get what you could've gotten for free.

Comment: Oops! Almost forgot Solemn Simulacrum.

Answer (score 3):

### Mountaincycling

Below is the card that sprang to mind when I read your question, and I didn't see it on OrigamiRobot's list so I thought I'd add it.  It doesn't ramp, but it helps get you mountains in the early game when you need them, and can be played as a big red beatstick later on when you have enough lands - quite versatile!  (There are other creatures like Valley Rannet and Igneous Pouncer that cycle for mountains and also other types of land, but if you're mono-R then they're of less interest to you.)

[image: Chartooth Cougar]

Comment: I was looking for "search" and "land". Good catch.